# LongListSelector GroupItemsPanel selection not working

Tags: windows-phone-7, longlistselector

I have created a `LongListSelector` that populates at runtime with data downloaded to the phone. The groups are all there and correct, the `GroupItemsPanel` looks correct too. My problem is that whenever I select from the `GroupItemsPanel` the list is scrolled to the bottom instead of to the group header I selected.

Here is my XAML code

```xml
<toolkit:LongListSelector ItemsSource="{Binding Institutions}"
                          GroupHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource GroupHeader}"
                          GroupItemTemplate="{StaticResource GroupItem}"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTmpl}"
                          Grid.Row="1">
    <toolkit:LongListSelector.GroupItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </toolkit:LongListSelector.GroupItemsPanel>
</toolkit:LongListSelector>

<DataTemplate x:Key="GroupHeader">
    <Border Background="{StaticResource OrangeHighlight}" 
            Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}" 
            Padding="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"/>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="GroupItem">
    <Border Background="{StaticResource OrangeHighlight}" 
            Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}" 
            Padding="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" 
                   Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}"/>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTmpl">
    <Grid>
        <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}"
                  Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxStyle}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

This is how I'm creating the `ItemsSource`. The data is grouped by the first character of the `Name` field.

```cs
public IEnumerable<GroupingLayer<string, Field>> Institutions
{
    get
    {
        if (m_oInstitutions == null)
            m_oInstitutions = new List<Field>();
        //
        var oGrouping = from oField in m_oInstitutions 
                        group oField by oField.Name[0].ToString().ToUpper() 
                        into oGroup select new GroupingLayer<string, Field>(oGroup);
        return oGrouping;
    }
}

public class Field
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class GroupingLayer<TKey, TElement> : IGrouping<TKey, TElement>
{
    private readonly IGrouping<TKey, TElement> m_oGrouping;

    public GroupingLayer(IGrouping<TKey, TElement> oUnit)
    {
        m_oGrouping = oUnit;
    }

    public TKey Key { get { return m_oGrouping.Key; } }

    public IEnumerator<TElement> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return m_oGrouping.GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return m_oGrouping.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Regardless of which item I select from the `GroupItemsPanel` the list is scrolled to the bottom. Even if I select the first item (usually "A") the list goes to the bottom. I have no idea why this is happening :/

Many thanks if you can help out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still can't explain why this particular problem was happening, but I have found a way to get the selection working normally.

Instead of using the `GroupingLayer` class I use an abstract of `List<>`.

```cs
public class KeyGroup<T> : List<T>
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
}
```

This means the `ItemsSource` is created like this (from a normal `List<>`):

```cs
List<Field> oFields;
List<KeyGroup<Field>> oGroups;
String sKey;
Bool bFound;
//
oFields = GetLiveData();
oGroups = new List<KeyGroup<Field>>();
//
foreach (var oField in oFields)
{
    sKey = oField.Name[0].ToString().ToUpper();
    bFound = false;
    //
    // Loop backwards through the groups if the fields are sorted
    for (int i = oGroups.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        if (oGroups[i].Key.Equals(sKey))
        {
            oGroups[i].Add(oField);
            bFound = true;
            break;
        }
    //
    if (!bFound)
    {
        oGroups.Add(new KeyGroup<Field>() { Key = sKey });
        oGroups[oGroups.Count - 1].Add(oField);
    }
}
//
// Set the ItemsSource to oGroups
myLongListSelector.ItemsSource = oGroups;
```

Using this model for the data seems to allow the selector to function properly, but jobs knows why it didn't work with the first approach...